# Infinity mirror room with emissive materials in Cycles

Tags: materials, mirror, reflection

Not getting reflections, except one iteration of faint lights. Corners are emissive, strength 10. Walls have roughness on 0. Max Bounces Total 48, Diffuse 8, Glossy 24.

Viewport:

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Increase metallic. Get it to 1 for perfect reflection. Real mirrors have a metal component responsible for reflection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).